# Apostrophe within Python lookbehind assertion

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use a Python regular expression to get the first token of a character-separated string. I don't want to treat backslashed separators as real separators, so I'm using a negative lookbehind assertion. When the separator is a comma, it works without problem.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match("(.*?)(?<!\\\\),.*", "Hello\, world!,This is a comma separated string,Third value").groups(1)[0]
'Hello\\, world!'
```

Whereas the exact same code by replacing the comma with an apostrophe does not work at all.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match("(.*?)(?<!\\\\)'.*", "Hello\' world!'This is an apostrophe separated string'Third value").groups(1)[0]
'Hello'
>>>
```

I'm using python 2.7.2, but I have the same behavior with Python 3 (tested on Ideone). The Python [re documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) does not indicate that `'` is a special character, so I'm really wondering, why is my `'` treated differently?

(Please, no comments: Who would want to have an apostrophe-separated file. Well... I do...)

Comment: Very odd. Seems like there isn't a difference between `ord("\'")` and `ord("'")`. Have you tried a non-escaped single quote in your search string?

Comment: No, there isn't -- escaping a non-escape character just gives you that character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print(repr("\'"),repr("\,"))
```

Results in:

```
"'" '\\,'
```

As you can see `"\'"` doesn't *actually* have a `\\` in it. Hence when you change it to `"\\'"` the pattern matches producing:

```
Hello\' world!
```

`"\'"` is actually an [escape sequence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> \' Single quote (')

Clearly, the reason

```
>>> ord("\'") == ord("'")
True
```

Is because `"\'"` **is** equivalent to `"'"`. It makes sense `\'` is an escape sequence:

```
>>> 'i\'ll'
"i'll"
```

Comment: Thank you. Just found that too. However, I'm surprised the behavior is not the same for `,`.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Indeed, that makes sense.